# Regular expression to restrict 'n' digits before and after decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I need a regex for restrict 10 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal point. i have tried with this

```
if (!(/^\d{1,10}(\.$|\.\d{1,2}$|$)/).test(value)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
<input id="input" type="number" />
```

It is working fine for input type **text**.But it is not working for type number.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4gmoL89/1/)

Please help me on this

Comment: you dont need to use type number if you are using regex

Comment: Thanks.Then how can we restrict user while typing

Comment: you code on fiddle is doing this, no?

Comment: But am doing this for hybrid app,so need to use type number for numeric keypad  https://jsfiddle.net/b4gmoL89/1/

Comment: The fiddle works. What's the problem?

Comment: i have updated the fiddle.i will not permit digits after decimal if i entered 10 digits before decimal

Comment: change for type text and insert "pattern=(your regex)" in the input and you can have a hybrid app

Comment: firefox v.46 doesn't allow to perform `keypress` event in your jsfiddle

Comment: You can use the pattern attribute of the input tag, a feature of html5.

Answer (score 7):

To restrict Decimal places before and after decimal this should work:

```js
function ValidateDecimalInputs(e) {

    var beforeDecimal =3;
    var afterDecimal = 2;
   
    $('#'+e.id).on('input', function () {
        this.value = this.value
          .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')            
          .replace(new RegExp("(^[\\d]{" + beforeDecimal + "})[\\d]", "g"), '$1') 
          .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         
          .replace(new RegExp("(\\.[\\d]{" + afterDecimal + "}).", "g"), '$1');   
    });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "textBox" onclick="ValidateDecimalInputs(this)"/>
```

Comment: Worked for me.Can you explain me how this is working?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
if(! (/^[0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{2}$/).test(1234567890.12)) {
}
```

Just use this regex `/^[0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{2}$/` in your code to verify if value is 10 digits before decimal and 2 after.

Answer (score 1):

**Parameters**

- `oninput`: Detect immediate changes to the `input` tag.
- `max`: Set the maximum value.
- `min`: Set the minimum value.
- `type`: Set what type of `input` tag you want.
- `value`: Set the current value.
- `step`: Set the amount to ascend or descend by.

---

```js
//(function(object){object.value=parseFloat(object.value).toFixed(2);})(this)

//(function(object){var val=object.value;object.value=val.slice(0,val.indexOf('.')+3);})(this)
```

```html
<input id="input" oninput="(function(object){object.value=parseFloat(object.value).toFixed(2);})(this)" type="number" value="0.00" step="0.01" min="0.00" max="9999999999.99" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HovyTech/pr91s7d4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
value=  (value.substr(0, value.indexOf(".")) + value.substr(value.indexOf("."), 2));
```

this will work as it will give all values before "." and only 2 values after "."

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, even with number type.

**JQuery**

```
$("body").on("keyup", ".patternCheck", function(){
        if(this.value.match(/^[0-9]{1,10}[.]{1}[0-9]{1,2}$/) == null)
        {
            $(this).val($(this).attr("pval"));
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr("pval", $(this).val());
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" value="0.0" pval="0.0" class="patternCheck">
```